# Jquery not working in Wordpress; function php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to add my script into my wordpress function.php file.

So far I have this:

```
<?php
function add_google_jquery() {
   if ( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery',   ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'add_google_jquery');

function menu_bar(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var navbar = $(".navbar");

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if(navbar.scrollTop() == 0){
              navbar.css("background", rgba(0,0,0,0));
            }
            else 
            {
              navbar.css("background", rgba(255,255,255,0));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'menu_bar');
?>
```

I had already tried using jQuery instead of $ and declaring $ = jQuery.

Comment: what about $j = jQuery.noConflict() ?

Comment: I think it's a very bad idea to add your javascript in functions.php. But you can try with passing $ in parameter  `$(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: is there a better way to do? Don't tell me I have to make my own plugin

Comment: What do you mean by "better" ...? A magic thing that do it without adding code ?

Comment: Well Xenofexs said is a very bad idea adding js in functionphp so i guess there is a proper way to do.

Comment: Yeah, this is a 2nd problem. For this, you should make a `.js` file, and include it in your header.php. If you use a theme, you should have a child-theme, with a `custom.js` somewhere...

Comment: I see, thank you. I will try this.

Comment: Suggest you have a fallback in case the call to the CDN for jQuery times out. If you can't get the file from the CDN for whatever reason, the page won't render.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Developer Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), you should add a dependency to json2 when you enqueue your add_google_query(). I don't think you need to run the wp_register_script() if you enqueue it as such (after you've de-registered the core version of jQuery):

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery',"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js", array("json2"));
```

I agree with @Random above that you should put the js in a separate file and call it via wp_enqueue_script() via an add_action on the get_header hook and put true in to load in the footer as such if you want the script to run in every template:

`function add_my_menu_bar() {
  wp_enqueue_script('my_menu_bar',"path-to-the-js-file.js", array("jquery"), false, true);
}
add_action('get_header','add_my_menu_bar');`

Good coding practice with jQuery and WordPress is not to use $ to identify a jQuery object. Recommend you get used to it. I generally write my jQuery dependent scripts using $ and then find/replace all with jQuery.

As a last point, I strongly recommend you do not edit the core functions.php file in wp-includes. That file will likely be overwritten in future WordPress version changes. Most, if not all, themes will have a functions.php file that will be included when the theme runs. That's a better place to put your functions and action hooks.